# SQL Self joining query

Tags: sql

I have a table in the following format.

```
Id   Orig_Id   Type 
11    1111    Internal
12    1111    Internal
13    1111    Internal
14    1112    External
15    1112    Internal
```

I want to retrieve all the Orig_Id's which has "ONLY" the Type as Internal. The query should return 1111.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT Orig_Id
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Orig_Id
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type <> 'Internal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Internal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

The first condition makes sure that the `Orig_Id` has no rows with `Type = Internal`. The second one makes sure that it has at least one `Internal`.

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/476108)</kbd>

Comment: You have one typo, should be `SELECT Orig_Id` in `online demo` you have this ok

Answer (score 1):

Just to check if there is only one `Type` and the only one is 'Internal'

```
SELECT Orig_Id
FROM (VALUES (11,1111,'Internal'),
    (12,1111,'Internal'),
    (13,1111,'Internal'),
    (14,1112,'External'),
    (15,1112,'Internal')) AS T(Id ,Orig_Id, Type)
GROUP BY Orig_Id
HAVING 
    -- There is one
    COUNT(DISTINCT Type) = 1
    -- and only one internal
    AND MIN(Type) = 'Internal'
```